# Apache Storm: get Topology name inside a Bolt

Tags: java, apache-storm

How can I get the name of the current topology inside a `BaseRichBolt` implementation? I see that I have access to the stormConfig Map and the `TopologyContext` from the `prepare()` call, but it isn't obvious how to get the name of the running topology from either of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it from the `config` map. 
Use `config.get(Config.TOPOLOGY_NAME)`

http://nathanmarz.github.io/storm/doc/backtype/storm/Config.html#TOPOLOGY_NAME

@ComputerDruid thanks for the correction